# Rendering JSON in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I was reading a book and in a chapter about Controllers when it talks about rendering stuff, for JSON it has an example like this but doesn't go in to details so I couldn't figure out the bigger picture that this example fits in:

```
render :json => @projects, :include => tasks
```

And also some example with JSONP using it with callback functions:

```
render :json => @record, :callback => 'updateRecordDisplay'
```

Can someone explain these?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You'll normally be returning [JSON](http://json.org/) either because:

A) You are building part / all of your application as a Single Page Application (SPA) and you need your client-side JavaScript to be able to pull in additional data without fully reloading the page.

*or*

B) You are building an API that third parties will be consuming and you have decided to use JSON to serialize your data.

<sub>Or, possibly, you are eating your own dogfood and doing *both*</sub>

In both cases `render :json => some_data` will JSON-ify the provided data.  The `:callback` key in the second example needs a bit more explaining (see below), but it is another variation on the same idea (returning data in a way that JavaScript can easily handle.)

#### Why `:callback`?

JSONP (the second example) is a way of getting around the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) that is part of every browser's built-in security.  If you have your API at `api.yoursite.com` and you will be serving your application off of `services.yoursite.com` your JavaScript will not (by default) be able to make `XMLHttpRequest` (XHR - aka ajax) requests from `services` to `api`.  The way people have been sneaking around that limitation (before the [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing spec was finalized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)) is by sending the JSON data over from the server *as if it was JavaScript instead of JSON*).  Thus, rather than sending back:

```
{"name": "John", "age": 45}
```

the server instead would send back:

```
valueOfCallbackHere({"name": "John", "age": 45})
```

Thus, a client-side JS application could create a `script` tag pointing at `api.yoursite.com/your/endpoint?name=John` and have the `valueOfCallbackHere` function (which would have to be defined in the client-side JS) called *with the data from this other origin*.)

Comment: and is it better not to use these techniques at all and use JSON-JBuilder and Eager Loading instead?
Or I am confused and they are two different things.?

Comment: @user1899082 - these techniques are actually *lower-level* concepts than what you will be worrying about when you use JBuilder, for example - there is no reason why you couldn't use JBuilder to make serializing your objects easier inside of your `to_json` methods - mixing and matching the two `render :json => some_object_that_uses_JBuilder_to_render_its_json` is (as far as I can tell) licit.

Comment: Thanks Sean, your explanation helped me to know about rendering json with callback, this solved one of my problem.

Answer (score 80):

What exactly do you want to know? ActiveRecord has methods that serialize records into JSON. For instance, open up your rails console and enter `ModelName.all.to_json` and you will see JSON output. `render :json` essentially calls `to_json` and returns the result to the browser with the correct headers. This is useful for AJAX calls in JavaScript where you want to return JavaScript objects to use. Additionally, you can use the `callback` option to specify the name of the callback you would like to call via JSONP.

For instance, lets say we have a `User` model that looks like this: `{name: 'Max', email:' m@m.com'}`

We also have a controller that looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        render json: @user
    end
end
```

Now, if we do an AJAX call using jQuery like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/users/5",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.name) // Will alert Max
    }        
});
```

As you can see, we managed to get the User with id 5 from our rails app and use it in our JavaScript code because it was returned as a JSON object. The callback option just calls a JavaScript function of the named passed with the JSON object as the first and only argument.

To give an example of the `callback` option, take a look at the following:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        render json: @user, callback: "testFunction"
    end
end
```

Now we can crate a JSONP request as follows:

```
function testFunction(data) {
    alert(data.name); // Will alert Max
};

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "/users/5";

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

The motivation for using such a callback is typically to circumvent the browser protections that limit cross origin resource sharing (CORS). JSONP isn't used that much anymore, however, because other techniques exist for circumventing CORS that are safer and easier.

Comment: Can you extend your example a bit ? Adding a `callback:` option in the `render` method, and then showing it inside the `Ajax` call.

Answer (score 19):

For the instance of

```
render :json => @projects, :include => :tasks
```

You are stating that you want to render `@projects` as JSON, and include the association `tasks` on the Project model in the exported data.

For the instance of

```
render :json => @projects, :callback => 'updateRecordDisplay'
```

You are stating that you want to render `@projects` as JSON, and wrap that data in a javascript call that will render somewhat like:

```
updateRecordDisplay({'projects' => []})
```

This allows the data to be sent to the parent window and bypass cross-site forgery issues.