# Adding server side support for JSONP in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code on the server side which renders a JSON.

```
render json: {status: 1}, status: :ok
```

I would like to add support for rendering JSONP, how do I do that ?

I've tried the following code & it didn't work:

```
render :json => {status: 1}, :jsonp => params[:jsonp], :status => :ok
```

Edit:

I'm getting now the error: '`because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`'

How do I tell rails to server application/javascript then ?

Comment: There you go ->> https://coderwall.com/p/xew0cw/render-a-jsonp-response-in-rails

Comment: someone explained what the `:callback` is doing ->> http://stackoverflow.com/a/14824664/2767755

Comment: What code lead you to this error ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit, render :js => {}, :callback => params[:jsonp], :status => :ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might be the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render json: {item: value}}
   if params[:callback]
     format.js { render :json => {item: value.to_json}, callback: params[:callback] }
   else
    format.json { render json: {item: value}}
   end
 end
```

Comment: respond_to do |format|
          format.js { render :json => {}, :callback => params[:jsonp], :status => :ok }
        end  didn't work

Comment: because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: sorry then i dont have any ideas. never dealt with that.